# GraphQL errors with proxy and and ServerParseError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, apollo-server

How do I fix the errors below?

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /localhost:3000/graphql from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.

[image]

Here is my `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./config/connection');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schemas');
//const routes = require('./routes');
const { authMiddleware } = require('./utils/auth');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: authMiddleware
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// if we're in production, serve client/build as static assets
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}

//app.use(routes);

db.once('open', () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(` Now listening on localhost:${PORT}`);
    console.log(`Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
  });
});
```

When I click on the POST error, it says it's coming from a login event handler

```
const handleFormSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

     // check if form has everything (as per react-bootstrap docs)
     const form = event.currentTarget;
     if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
     }

    try {
      const { data } = await login({
        variables: {...userFormData} 
      });
      Auth.login(data.login.token);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      setShowAlert(true);
    }

    setUserFormData({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
    });
  };
```

All 3 errors point to that `handleFormSubmit` function when I expand them in DevTools.

Here is my `package.json` in the `client` folder

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "secure": false,
```

Here is the full POST error
[image]
(I fixed the uri too)

This is my `app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import SearchBooks from './pages/SearchBooks';
import SavedBooks from './pages/SavedBooks';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  request: operation => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      }
    })
  },
  uri: '/graphql'
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Router>
          <>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={SearchBooks} />
              <Route exact path='/saved' component={SavedBooks} />
              <Route render={() => <h1 className='display-2'>Wrong page!</h1>} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you post the reply of the graphql request ?
it seems from the error that the server is responding with a non json reply.

Comment: I have also noticed that you are sending an odd uri
http://localhost:3000/localhost:3001/graphql.
can you also clarify which proxy you are using ?

Comment: Where is the reply of the graphql request?

Comment: you can find it in the network tab in chrome dev tools. It should be a post request to the requested uri localhost:3000/localhost:3001/graphql.

Comment: okay, I added the screenshot and also fixed the uri

Comment: Please also mention that you are using create-react-app.

Comment: I can't find where you set your uri in frontend part. You have to change the uri to just `/graphql` instead of `/localhost:3001/graphql`.
Please share the Apollo client configuration as the error is not sourced from the form.

Comment: I added the app.js code above

Comment: This is what is attached to the Proxy error: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219905/discussion-between-antoine-raoul-iscaros-and-deanna-martinez).